# Agregar una columna a una vista en sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una vista en sql server 2014 pero deseo que en la vista se agregue una columna tipo boolean, es posible hacerlo?

Comment: Sí es posible. Sólo hay que modificar la definición de la vista para agregarla.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes modificar la definición de la vista medante SSMS. Si lo que quieres es hacerlo mediante código, me temo que solo es posible definiendo de nuevo toda la vista.

Si tenemos la siguiente vista:

```
CREATE VIEW MiVista as
select Campo1
from MiTabla
```

y quiero añadirle un campo, deberé realizar un `ALTER` con la definición completa de la vista

```
ALTER VIEW MiVista as
select Campo1, Campo2
from MiTabla
```

Debes hacer referencia solo al nombre del campo, independientemente del tipo de datos.

Si lo que quieres es que te muestre un campo boolean inexistente en la base de datos, entonces la solución es sencilla

```
ALTER VIEW MiVista as
select Campo1, 1 as Campo2
from MiTabla
```

Comment: Talvez me explico mejor, tengo la siguiente vista: select id,persona, direccion from persona. Ahora lo que deseo es que a esa vista se le agreggue una columna de tipo bit pero esa no existe campo en la base de datos ya que la deseo temporal únicamente para que en el aplicativo sirva para verificar un proceso.

Comment: @MarioAntonioRuizCarrillo he editado la respuesta e incluido el campo que quieres.